# how to sign in googlemap apk which key i used?

Tags: android

I'm creating Google map application i get  my key from cmd using this command and get key from Google console ant tested in mobile is work fine  but when i create apk and execution mobile is not show any map if i run directly application from eclipse to mobile is show map whats wrong in my sign in method? what keys i write when making apk

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\S-tek
\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass and
 roid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same key as signing keystore instead of android default keys for getting map api keys .

For example: you are using xyz.keystore file to sign your application then instead of debug.keystore put the path and password of xyz.keystore file to generate the Map api keys.

Comment: what password i write when click on export sign in key    below  Use exiting keystore or create new story?  ask password and confirm password when click on next screen ask alias:  password confirm password  what i wirte in these fields

Comment: what i write in alias name and what i wirte in password

Comment: so confusing  my map will show on mobile when i directly run form eclipse tomobile problem is only sign in apk so what do i do

Comment: keep the same password as entered earlier and in alias keep any short name for the key or anything which you think is can remembered.

Comment: you can set the password as your desire !

Comment: I think you have to search first for how to sign apk.

Comment: give me any example im confuse what u say

Comment: Yes you can enter any password for alias rather than the earlier but you need to remember it, bcz it asks for the password when second time signing

Comment: are you done with creating new keystore and signing your build with that?

Comment: when click on export sign in first screen ask kewystore location and password confirm password   then second screen ask  alais name password confirmpassword wht i wtite there

Comment: whatever information you wants can put there just you need to remember it, in case you have to update your app on google play store you have to sign the apk with same keystore and then you will need this information

Comment: i get it my self in first screen where is ask keystore location i  select .adroid/debug.keystore   innext screen i write androiddebugkey  and password  android now is show on mobile thnx

Answer (score 0):

to sign your apk

first have some tips from official site of android :

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: i get api key  from  googleconsole  map will show on mobile when directly run from eclipse but is not show afgter sign in apk